# How do I ask chefs who don't speak in English if they can torch sashimi, in writing?

Tags: japan, dietary-restrictions

I like Japanese sashimi better when  partially cooked — partially grilled, blow-torched (see images under-neath), or seared.

[image]

I plan to print this request in Japanese, and show printout to restaurants in Japan whenever no-one speaks English. I know many Japanese don't speak English, and I don't speak Japanese.

#### [I input this in Google Translate](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=google+translate):

> I had this question written down, because I can't speak Japanese.
>
> i don't like the taste of raw fish. So can you please partially cook the seafood on  sushi: either by partially grilling, blow-torching, or searing? Many other restaurants have blow-torched their sushi for me.

Can someone please improve Google's translation beneath? Bold sentence is wrong — Google wrongly translated 'blow-torched' as 'baked'.

> 日本語を話すことができないので、この質問を書き留めました。
>
> 生の魚の味が好きではありません。それで、あなたは、あなたの寿司の上にシーフードを部分的に焼くことができますか：部分的に焼くこと、ブロートーチすること、**他にもたくさんのレストランが私のために寿司を吹いてくれました**

By the way, isn't the term ['aburi'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sushi#Neta) too specific?

> *Aburi* style refers to *nigiri* sushi where the fish is partially grilled (topside) and partially raw.

1. I need all seafood (not just fish) and sushi (not just [*nigiri*](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-sushi-sashimi-and-nigiri)) partially cooked.
2. But I don't care the cooking method. Wikipedia quote states "grilled".

[Japanese Stack Exchange](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799) bans proofreading or translation questions.

Comment: If this question does not yield satisfactory results, you might at least try some other machine translation services (Microsoft has one, or at least used to, under the Bing brand).

Comment: Have you filled in your doctor on this plan and gotten his sign-off, or *would you be embarrassed if he knew?*  A quick googling of the reasons to exclude raw fish for certain patients suggests to me that searing won't suffice, I could be wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the 2nd sentence in the 2nd paragraph is not well-formed. あなたは、あなたの - "anata wa, anata no" include "you" which they'll know you're referring to them, so can be omitted. It also has シーフード which is literally "seafood". 魚介類 is also "seafood": fish,

Comment: why not just avoiding raw seafood recipes? there are plenty of cooked food choices in the japanese cuisine

Comment: Your doctor must have misunderstood. You are talking about seared seafood. I don’t believe this has any health-related benefits. The Reddit post you linked to talks about explicitly fully cooked seafood rather than just seared (which could indeed have health benefits if you don’t trust the freshness or quality of the fish). Do you want the seafood to be fully cooked, as in the reddit post? If so, just avoid sushi and sashimi and eat any of the rest of the wonderful Japanese cuisine. If not, just enjoy what the chef serves you and trust them to have the right stuff.

Comment: @jcaron I removed part on Doctor that's befuddling people.

Comment: I appreciate that this doesn't answer your question (so I won't post it as such), but there is a lot of food to enjoy beyond sashimi in Japan. For example: curry, okonomiyaki, gyoza, karaage, ramen, udon, soba, donburi, takoyaki, teppanyaki, etc. so _if you're worried that you might struggle to find something to eat, don't be_. I dislike most fish (tuna and salmon are OK) and never struggle to find something to eat. Even most conveyor sushi restaurants will have options without sashimi.

Comment: If you can't eat raw fish, why would you go to a sushi restaurant?

Comment: The problem is that there's really no such thing as "cooked sashimi", period. Why don't you just order grilled fish, or aburi nigiri sushi pieces?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suspect you're not going to like this answer, but **I think you're going about this the wrong way**.

In Japan, the idea of "customizing" dishes like this is basically unknown: the chef makes dishes designed to taste good, and your choices are to order them or not order them.  Handing over a card like that is going to cause **confusion and bewilderment**, and not only are they unlikely to comply, but you'll likely be seen as rude and entitled.  (Especially with the current near-incomprehensible machine translation, where the last phrase comes off as almost accusatory, but that's another story.)

The second problem is that "grilled sashimi" is not a thing, pretty much by definition: once cooked, it's no longer sashimi. And in a sushi context, *aburi* is indeed a reference to a specific style of nigirizushi (not sashimi) usually quickly grilled with a blowtorch.

Instead, I'd recommend you find some existing Japanese dishes that match your requirements.

- You're already identified aburi as an option, and if ordering piece by piece (not set courses) it's entirely possible to order just aburi at many sushi places.  (Beware that not all 
  sushi places offer aburi, particularly more traditional ones.).
- *Tataki* (たたき) is another common style of quickly searing fish or meat on a grill so the inside is still raw, with bonito tataki (カツオのたたき *katsuo no tataki*) a particularly common izakaya staple.

Comment: _"In Japan, the idea of "customizing" dishes like this is basically unknown"_ - Indeed, even at a burger restaurant chain, a friend who has celiac disease was turned down for a burger without the buns (he was a JLPT N2 holder at the time, IIRC, so he could certainly communicate what he wanted and why). I mean, some places might be willing to do it, but it's certainly not the norm, as you say.

Comment: I would not limit this to Japan, but in most countries consider it rude to order food at a restaurant and tell the chef how I expect him to do his job.